Issue found: Violation of Misleading Claims policy with In-app experience icon
We all of a sudden started getting these messages about our icon we generate for our white label app.  The process is still the same and nothing has changed so we aren't sure why we keep getting these messages.  We even appealed and weeks later still no response.  The icons all look right and there is no icon that is just blank.  The emulator looks fine too that has the same code base.
Issue found: Violation of Misleading Claims policy
Your app contains content that doesn't comply with the Misleading Claims policy.
Your app is improperly categorized, including but not limited to the app rating or app category.
Issue details
We found an issue in the following area(s):
Hi-res icon (en-US): Please see attached screenshot HI_RES_ICON-9292.png
In-app experience: Please see attached screenshot IN_APP_EXPERIENCE-6826.png
About the Misleading Claims policyWe don’t allow apps that contain false or misleading information or claims, including in the description, title, icon, and screenshots, such as apps that are improperly categorized, including but not limited to, the app rating or app category.



As written, this question appears to be attempting to debate a Google policy decision regarding the Play Store, and that is off-topic. If your real question is "how would Google wind up with a white launcher icon?", we need much more of a [mcve]. What little of an example that you have provided already looks troublesome, in that -v4 has been pointless for nearly a decade, xxxhdpi only works on API level 18 and above, and we don't know how you are testing your launcher icon behavior.

Can you just provide real world answers?

Only if you can provide a real world scenario with a [mcve].

You can't, because this could be a bug or policy which someone may of found a way to work around.  Just like this which can't be reproduced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46444975/apple-is-killing-white-labeled-ios-apps-what-should-we-do/51003458#51003458

I was able to submit two updates using the Android Studio icon creator instead of Icon Kitchen.  There was no monochrome in the Android Studio icon creator so I am assuming something is off on those images.
